# How to avoid warning message "is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors" messages when configuring Custom Permission Evaluator

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Configuring custom GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration in Spring Boot generates "is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors" messages when configuring Custom Permission Evaluator, it doesnt have any @Autowired (Custom Permission Evaluator Neither)

```
    2020-05-24 19:43:17.430  INFO 9848 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'customPermissionEvaluator' of type [test.data.security.CustomPermissionEvaluator] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
    2020-05-24 19:43:17.455  INFO 9848 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.ObjectPostProcessorConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.ObjectPostProcessorConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
    2020-05-24 19:43:17.458  INFO 9848 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'objectPostProcessor' of type [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.AutowireBeanFactoryObjectPostProcessor] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
    2020-05-24 19:43:17.460  INFO 9848 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler@68b734a8' of type [org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
    2020-05-24 19:43:17.461  INFO 9848 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'securityMethodConfig' of type [test.data.config.SecurityMethodConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$39af5526] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
    2020-05-24 19:43:17.465  INFO 9848 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'methodSecurityMetadataSource' of type [org.springframework.security.access.method.DelegatingMethodSecurityMetadataSource] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
```

I use this configuration, and just by adding it that warnings were displayed

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
class SecurityMethodConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

    private CustomPermissionEvaluator customPermissionEvaluator;

    public SecurityMethodConfig( CustomPermissionEvaluator customPermissionEvaluator ) {
        this.customPermissionEvaluator=customPermissionEvaluator;
    }

    @Override
    public MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
        DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler methodSecurityExpressionHandler = new DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
        methodSecurityExpressionHandler.setPermissionEvaluator(customPermissionEvaluator);
        return methodSecurityExpressionHandler;
    }
}
```

I even try without custom permisson evaluator, with proxyTargetClass = true and without it and same messages were displayed

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
class SecurityMethodConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {
   @Override
    public MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
        DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler methodSecurityExpressionHandler = new DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
        return methodSecurityExpressionHandler;
    }
}
```

Permissions works fine, message is just annoying when initializing app and I want to know what I'm doing wrong when configuring custom permission evaluator in this way or how I can fix it to get zero messages of this kind?

If I remove that configuration code, that messages arent displayed.